# What is the meaning of “lâcher son maillot”?

Tags: expressions, sens

I have heard my French friend use the expression like “*il a lâché son maillot*” if I heard it right. The context was the Tour de France. I am not sure if it is an expression or just different word usage (as compared with English).

Comment: Welcome here! Sorry, the title was correct, but I've changed it, it must match the language used in the body of the question. Also you can ask for the meaning of something (you'll get an answer in English), but an answer will not necessarily provide you with a perfect English wording.

Comment: Thanks for changing the title and giving an explanation as to why .Which I believe will be useful for future references :)

Comment: I know what it is but I can't explain in english :-) see [Cancellara prêt à lâcher son maillot ](http://www.francetv.fr/sport/cancellara-pret-a-lacher-son-maillot-9496)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *maillot* here refers to *le maillot jaune*, which in cycling event [Le Tour de France](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tour_de_France_%28cyclisme%29) is awarded to the currently leading competitor (in matter of time).

Knowing that, the expression *prêt à lâcher son maillot* can be translated to *ready to (give up/lose) his (leading position/leader status)*.

Comment: Actually, the _maillot jaune_ is awarded to the leader in matter of time. The _maillot vert_ is awarded to the leader in matter of points.

Comment: I guess I couldn't be bothered to learn even one of this game's rules in a lifetime. You must be right, I edit, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The full expression is "lâcher son maillot jaune" and it is used only in the context of the Tour de France.

It means dropping out from the first place and thus giving one's own yellow jacket up to another racer.